# Animating rectangle in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a password box and under it i have a rectangle. I want the rectangle to expand from 0 to 200 width when the password box gets focus.
this is the XAML code

```xml
<Rectangle x:Name="passwordbox_underline" Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="1" Fill="YellowGreen" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

<PasswordBox Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Style="{StaticResource hi}" CaretBrush="White" FontStretch="Expanded" x:Name="pass" GotFocus="pass_GotFocus"/>
```

And this is the C# code:

```cs
private void pass_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
            myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Duration = duration;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, passwordbox_underline);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("Rectangle.Width"));
            myDoubleAnimation1.From = 0;
            myDoubleAnimation1.To = 200;

            sb.Begin();

        }
```

But it doesn't work and nothing happens. Where's the problem?

Comment: You do not need a Storyboard at all: `passwordbox_underline.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.WidthProperty, myDoubleAnimation1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. There we a couple minor issues.

First, you never added your `DoubleAnimation` to your `Storyboard`. You need the following

```
sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
```

Next, your property path is a bit off. You're working on the `Rectangle`, so you don't specify it as part of the path. It is just be "Width".

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("Width"));
```

Last, your rectangle had no height so it still was not visible when animated. I added a height of 5 for testing.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="passwordbox_underline" Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="1" Fill="YellowGreen" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Width="0" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Putting it all together, this code snippet will animate (but don't forget to add a height to your rectangle):

```
 Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
 DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
 myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
 Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
 sb.Duration = duration;
 Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, passwordbox_underline);
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("Width"));
 myDoubleAnimation1.From = 0;
 myDoubleAnimation1.To = 200;
 sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
 sb.Begin();
```